# Getting compilation warnings for non-prototype declarations

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-warnings, c99

In C, function declarations can be prototype or non-prototype declarations.  For example, consider the following minimal program:

```
int foo (); /* non-prototype declaration */

int bar (void); /* prototype declaration */

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Although in C99 non-prototype declarations are obsolete, I cannot get GCC to complain about them.  For example, compiling the above program with GCC and all errors enabled just succeeds:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Werror -Wall test.c
$
```

Is there any way to persuade GCC to emit warnings  for function declarations that aren't prototypes?

(Question inspired by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827247/266449) by [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the option you are looking for is `-Wstrict-prototypes`

Comment: I thought that would be included by `-Wall`, but obviously I was wrong. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `gcc` with `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall` options doesn't issue any warning for the old style function declarations but C doesn't require the implementation to issue a diagnostic in presence of the old style function declarations.

C characterizes the use of  old style function declaration as obsolescent since C89 but it it still valid C code (in C89/C99/C11).